# UiTable view Cell

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, text

Can i write some text in the row of table view, after running the application.
I know that we can edit the table View before running the application, but after the Build, Can i write on the table view some text.
If so, coul;d anyone share how it is possible?

thanks
Rizwan

Answer (score 0):

first you have to access the cell in which you want to write text then access the component in which you want to write text.

to get cell use

```
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath];
```